# Trigonometry application

Tags: trigonometry

A communication mast is supported by the ropes which are attached from the ground to a point half way up the mast. the communication mast is $60$ m tall. If the distance from the base of the mast to the point. where the rope i secured to ground is $30\sqrt{3}$ m,find the angled angles made by the rope with the horizontal and hence calculate the length of each of the support ropes

Comment: This is not a high school homework site. Please show what problem are you facing.

Comment: Try to find where the 30/60/90 right triangle is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. Construct a right angle triangle from the mast, the ground and one of the ropes. Draw a diagram of this triangle.
2. In the question you are given the lengths of two sides of this triangle. What are they ?
3. Which trigonometric ratio can you calculate from the lengths of these two sides ?
4. How does this help you find the angle that the rope makes with the ground (you can assume the ground is horizontal) ?
5. Which theorem connects the length of the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle with the lengths of the other two sides ?
6. The rope is the hypotenuse in your triangle. How can you use the theorem from (5) and the known lengths of the other two sides to find the length if the rope ?